# Solutions to linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Am I right in thinking that the following augmented matrix equation only has one solution:

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 4\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 10   
\end{bmatrix} $

i.e., if the unknown variables are x, y and z, it follows that $y = 4\  and \  z = 10 $ are the only known variables, hence there can only be one solution.

Comment: no. the first column variable can be anything. so this system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: It depends on the field. There are only finitely many solutions over a finite field (e.g., coding theory). Note that $x$ is arbitrary. Hence over an infinite field we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm guessing it has several solutions because there are 3 unknown variables and only two equations. I was a bit unsure because of the zeros in the first column.